# LZW Compression/ Expansion in Java

Tags: java, lzw

I am trying to use the [LZW code provided by Princeton](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/LZW.java) and modify it to vary the size of codeword from 9 to 16 bits. I am unsure of how to do this, but was thinking of maybe using a loop since the size needs to be increased when all codewords of the size before were used. I am just looking for a useful direction to go in, since this is an assignment that I am having trouble starting.

```
public class LZW {
    private static final int R = 256;        // number of input chars
    private static final int L = 4096;       // number of codewords = 2^W
    private static final int W = 12;         // codeword width

public static void compress() { 
    String input = BinaryStdIn.readString();
    TST<Integer> st = new TST<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        st.put("" + (char) i, i);
    int code = R+1;  // R is codeword for EOF

    while (input.length() > 0) {
        String s = st.longestPrefixOf(input);  // Find max prefix match s.
        BinaryStdOut.write(st.get(s), W);      // Print s's encoding.
        int t = s.length();
        if (t < input.length() && code < L)    // Add s to symbol table.
            st.put(input.substring(0, t + 1), code++);
        input = input.substring(t);            // Scan past s in input.
    }
    BinaryStdOut.write(R, W);
    BinaryStdOut.close();
} 


public static void expand() {
    String[] st = new String[L];
    int i; // next available codeword value

    // initialize symbol table with all 1-character strings
    for (i = 0; i < R; i++)
        st[i] = "" + (char) i;
    st[i++] = "";                        // (unused) lookahead for EOF

    int codeword = BinaryStdIn.readInt(W);
    if (codeword == R) return;           // expanded message is empty string
    String val = st[codeword];

    while (true) {
        BinaryStdOut.write(val);
        codeword = BinaryStdIn.readInt(W);
        if (codeword == R) break;
        String s = st[codeword];
        if (i == codeword) s = val + val.charAt(0);   // special case hack
        if (i < L) st[i++] = val + s.charAt(0);
        val = s;
    }
    BinaryStdOut.close();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    if      (args[0].equals("-")) compress();
    else if (args[0].equals("+")) expand();
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal command line argument");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you understand what the constants at the very top are for?

Comment: @Jongware I think so. I believe W is what I would be modifying? Since it is the codeword width? Only I would be changing it to vary from 9 to 16 bits?

Comment: Glancing over this example, I'm not so sure this uses *variable length* encoding. `W` starts out as 12 (which is an odd value to start with, as it is wider than necessary) and never gets modified. So changing `W` is, by far, not the *only* change needed.

Comment: @Jongware oh okay, I see what you're saying, I think. Instead of changing W, should I create new variables then? I'm not sure how to go about this if it doesn't require modifying W...

Comment: *Must* you modify this code? You could start at reading up on the LZW algorithm, and pay attention to where the code word length gets changed.

Comment: @Jongware For my assignment, I am told to modify this code to make it fulfill certain requirements. The first requirement is the changing of bits so it varies from 9 to 16 bits.

Comment: I think you need to add one bit to the size when the number of words stored using the current bitlength = the next power of 2. So if you start using 9 bits, then you can encode words using 9 bits up until you get to the 512th word (2 ^ 9). When you get here, you must switch the bitlength to 10.